# Sass error: selector groups may not be extended

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm getting an error when attempting to compile my SCSS file into CSS. The error reads: "selector groups may not be extended" in reference to this line `@extend .btn, .btn-link;`.

Note: I'm importing Bootstrap to use in my main scss file.

Full snippet:

```
button {
    @extend .btn, .btn-link;
    background-color: $lf-green;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    &:hover {
        background: rgba(5,97,43,0.9);
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

For posterity: The reason I couldn't do this was because I was using lib-sass via node-sass, which doesn't mesh with the current version of sass available through traditional means https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#reporting-sass-compilation-and-syntax-issues.

Comment: It's not clear, actually. That's why I posted the question. It would be more helpful if you linked me to the docs where this is covered.

Comment: The docs are a single page, it shouldn't be hard to find it on your own: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#multiple_extends

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works in one instance of Sass (latest version), and not in another (same version).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you cannot extend multiple selectors this way.

Try using this:

```
@extend .btn;
@extend .btn-link;
```

Although that seems a little repetitive, but works fine in my codes.

EDIT: while reading through [SASS_REFERENCE](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#multiple_extends), I found that:

> Multiple extends can also be written using a comma-separated list of selectors. For example, @extend .error, .attention is the same as @extend .error; @extend.attention.

I did found it [in the changelog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html#3115) that this format was first introduced in version 3.1.15, so I suppose you are using an older version of Sass than that.

I strongly encourage you to upgrade to the latest version, as it has a lot of great features, just make sure your codes are not broken by an update, although most of the inconsistencies can be worked out rather easily.

Comment: Oddly, I'm using Sass 3.3.4 (Maptastic Maple), which should have this capability. I'm not sure if using the Yeoman web-app generator (grunt-sass) is changing something however.

Comment: Ah, looks like I used libsass, which could explain the oddities: https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#reporting-sass-compilation-and-syntax-issues

Comment: That explains the issue indeed.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot extend more than one selector.

Comment: This is [obviously not true](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#multiple_extends).